# How can I save the weights and biases in my neural network after training it using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, neural-network, tensorflow.js

I built a neural network based on Michael Nielsen's Python code in his online book NeuralNetworksAndDeepLearning.  I used JavaScript, and instead of Numpy, I used Tensorflow.js. The network is working, but I want to find a way to save the weights and biases after training.  I only used Tensorflow for its matrix/vector operations, as I wanted to follow Nielsen's book and learn how neural network work.  I believe the Layers API provides a way to save models, but I'm trying to do this without relying on Layers. Thanks for your help.

```js
export class Network {
  constructor(sizes) {
    this.num_layers = sizes.length;
    this.sizes = sizes;
    this.biases = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < sizes.length; i++) {
      this.biases.push(tf.randomNormal([sizes[i], 1]));
    }
    this.weights = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < sizes.length - 1; j++) {
      this.weights.push(tf.randomNormal([sizes[j + 1], sizes[j]]));
    }
  }
  shuffleArray(array) {
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
    }
  }
  feedforward(act) {
    let a = act;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.num_layers - 1; i++) {
      a = tf.tidy(() => tf.sigmoid(this.weights[i].dot(a).add(this.biases[i])));
    }
    return a;
  }

  SGD(training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, eta, test_data = null) {
    let n_test;
    let n = training_data.length;
    if (test_data) n_test = test_data.length;
    for (let j = 0; j < epochs; j++) {
      this.shuffleArray(training_data);
      let mini_batches = [];
      for (let k = 0; k < n; k += mini_batch_size) {
        mini_batches.push(training_data.slice(k, k + mini_batch_size));
      }
      mini_batches.forEach(mb => {
        [this.weights, this.biases] = tf.tidy(() =>
          this.update_mini_batch([...mb], eta)
        );
      });
      if (test_data) {
        console.log(`Epoch ${j}: ${this.evaluate(test_data)} / ${n_test}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Epoch ${j} complete`);
      }
      console.log("Epoch complete:");
      console.log("Weights:");
      this.weights.forEach(x => x.print());
      console.log("Biases:");
      this.biases.forEach(x => x.print());
    }
  }

  update_mini_batch(mini_batch, eta) {
    //console.log(tf.memory().numTensors);
    let nabla_b = [];
    let nabla_w = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.num_layers - 1; i++) {
      nabla_b.push(tf.zeros(this.biases[i].shape));
      nabla_w.push(tf.zeros(this.weights[i].shape));
    }
    let x, y;
    mini_batch.forEach(data => {
      x = data[0];
      y = data[1];
      let delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w;
      [delta_nabla_b, delta_nabla_w] = this.backprop(x, y);
      nabla_b = nabla_b.map((nb, i) => {
        return nb.add(delta_nabla_b[i]);
      });
      nabla_w = nabla_w.map((nw, i) => {
        return nw.add(delta_nabla_w[i]);
      });
    });

    let weights = this.weights.map((w, i) => {
      return w.sub(tf.mul(nabla_w[i], eta / mini_batch.length));
    });
    let biases = this.biases.map((b, i) => {
      return b.sub(tf.mul(nabla_b[i], eta / mini_batch.length));
    });
    this.weights.forEach((x, i) => {
      x.dispose();
      this.biases[i].dispose();
    });

    return [weights, biases];
  }
  backprop(x, y) {
    let nabla_b = [];
    let nabla_w = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.num_layers - 1; i++) {
      nabla_b.push(tf.zeros(this.biases[i].shape));
      nabla_w.push(tf.zeros(this.weights[i].shape));
    }
    let activation = x;
    let activations = [x];
    let zs = [];
    this.biases.forEach((b, i) => {
      let z = this.weights[i].dot(activation).add(b);
      zs.push(z);
      activation = z.sigmoid();
      activations.push(activation);
    });
    let delta = this.cost_derivative(
      activations[activations.length - 1],
      y
    ).mul(this.sigmoid_prime(zs[zs.length - 1]));
    nabla_b[nabla_b.length - 1] = delta;
    nabla_w[nabla_w.length - 1] = delta.dot(
      activations[activations.length - 2].transpose()
    );
    for (let i = this.num_layers - 2; i > 0; i--) {
      let z = zs[i - 1];
      let sp = this.sigmoid_prime(z);
      delta = this.weights[i]
        .transpose()
        .dot(delta)
        .mul(sp);
      nabla_b[i - 1] = delta;
      nabla_w[i - 1] = delta.dot(activations[i - 1].transpose());

      //sp.dispose();
    }

    return [nabla_b, nabla_w];
  }
  evaluate(test_data) {
    let sum = 0;
    test_data.forEach(data => {
      let x = tf.tidy(() => this.feedforward(data[0]).argMax());
      let y = data[1].argMax();

      let xvalue = x.dataSync()[0];
      let yvalue = y.dataSync()[0];

      if (xvalue === yvalue) {
        sum++;
      }
      x.dispose();
    });
    return sum;
  }
  cost_derivative(output_activations, y) {
    return output_activations.sub(y);
  }
  sigmoid_prime(z) {
    return z.sigmoid().mul(tf.sub(1, z.sigmoid()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the layers API, it is possible to get the weights of a model, by using the `getWeights` on a layer. And there are different methods to save a model: in the localStorage, on disk,...

Since you're using your own implementation of network, you can simply save the model weights using localStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem('weights', weights).
```

Then when loading the model, you can check if there are some weights already stored or not and retrieved then

Comment: Thank you, this is getting me on the right track.  My weights and biases are arrays of tensor objects.  Do you know how I can save these to localStorage and recover them as tensor objects?  I tried using JSON.stringify() when setting the item, and JSON.parse() when retrieving it, however it appears some information was lost.  For example, I could no longer use the tf.print() function on my tensors.  Do you know if there is a better way to store the tensors so as to fully recover them?

Comment: Instead of saving the tensors to local storage, I could use dataSync to store the underlying array.  Then from that I could recreate the tensors.  However, if it were possible to save the tensors to localStorage directly, that would be lovely.

Comment: No, there is no way you could save a tf.tensor directly to localStorate. You only can retrieve the underlying array and store it as a string. There is this anwer that explains how to retrieve a tensor from a string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55937647/recreate-tensor-from-string

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize any tensor by using the [`tensor.array()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.array) (or [`tensor.arraySync()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Tensor.arraySync)) function.

**Code sample**

The following code sample will serialize your weights into a string.

```js
const t = tf.tensor2d([[1,2], [3,4]]); // sample tensor
const dataArray = t.arraySync();
const serializedString = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
console.log(serializedString); // outputs: [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

You could now take the resulting string and save it to disk (when using Node.js) or store it via localStorage in the browser (see below).

To deserialize the data you can then use the [`tf.tensor`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tensor) function:

```js
const serializedString = '[[1,2],[3,4]]';
const dataArray = JSON.parse(serializedString);
const t = tf.tensor(dataArray);
t.print();
```

`t` is then the same tensor as above, the output of the code is:

```js
Tensor
    [[1, 2],
     [3, 4]]
```

**Using localStorage**

To save the serialized string into localStorage and retrieve it, you can use the following code:

```js
localStorage.setItem('myTensor', serializedString); // save tensor
const serializedString = localStorage.getItem('myTensor'); // load tensor
```